# Query Folder name with role associated to it

Tags: soql, metadata-api, workbench, folder

I'm trying to get the role names associated with the folder but I'm not getting hold of it. Here is what I have tried:

```
Select Id, Name, isActive, Folder.Name from EmailTemplate
where Folder.Name = 'test'
```

I have tried adding `UserRole.Name or Profile.Name` but none of this works and if this is not possible is there a way to retrieve through metadata api using workbench?

I'm trying to get the selected values that users have selected in `Shared To` o the right hand box in the image.

Here is the image as a ref:
[image]

Comment: It's many to one. That means you are looking for some sort of child object. In this case, I believe you would want to find [`FolderShare`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_foldershare.htm) records.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, but you can't "query" foldershare. You could use the metadata listMetadata or you can retrieve it via metadata calls, but it's nothing you can get in a SOAP, REST, Bulk, or Tooling API query.

Comment: @sfdcfox: So you saying its not possible to retrieve the information?

Comment: Yeah I didn't say you could get it via SOQL. I'm not sure how to retrieve easily (or why you would even want to), just saying that's the object to look at.